# Is it possible to trigger bootstraps dropdown creation manually? (VueJS)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

It seems all the VueJS bootstrap components were built on version `1.x` and I get nothing but errors (even with packages claiming to support 2.0) when trying to use any of the packages with Vue 2.x

Is it possible to trigger bootstraps dropdown creation on elements from the `componentCreated` life cycle?

e.g.

```
export default {
    componentCreated() {
        $(el).createDropdown();
    }
}
```

I've looked through the src of bootstraps dropdown but I cannot figure out how to call it on the element to initialize it as a dropdown.

Any help on this would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very not sure about your bootstrap code but I dont see any `componentCreated` hook in vue [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). I think the hook you should be using is either [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) or [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).

Following is vue lifecycle diagram:

[image]

In [bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#via-javascript) and in [older versions](https://getbootstrap.com/2.0.4/javascript.html#dropdowns) as well, following is the JS code to create dropdown:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Comment: I thought this only toggled the `.hide` class on the dropdown, and you're right, I was thinking of `componentUpdated` from directives

Comment: @Datsik yes you are right: `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` toggles dropdown, I am not sure of this code: `$(el).createDropdown();`.